# Cannot use import statement outside a module - Node JS - (While using translate module) - How to solve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, translate

I am using node version 16 and the whole project is using `require` to `import`. Like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Currently, we are planning to use a npm module called translate
https://www.npmjs.com/package/translate

But for this package, we can't use `require`. We have to use `import`. Like this

```
import translate from "translate";
```

I tried importing it directly like this but I am getting this error. **Cannot use import statement outside a module**

Later I tried adding the below code in package.json.

```
  {
   "type": "module",
  }
```

But then I got the below error.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
                 ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
```

I also tried using `.mjs` Like this in `translate.mjs`

```
import translate from 'translate';

  (function () {
    exports.translateDatas = async () => {
      const text = await translate('Hello world', 'es');
      console.log(text);
    };
  })();
```

Then in `translaction.js`

```
const translateDatas = require('../utils/translate.mjs');

const translateService = async (text) => {
  return translateDatas(text);
};

module.exports = {
  translateService,
};
```

But even in this case, I am getting the below error

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /src/utils/translate.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of /src/utils/translate.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

Below is my package.json file

```
            {
          "name": "nodejs-express-boilerplate",
          "version": "1.7.0",
          "description": "Create a Node.js app for building production-ready RESTful APIs using Express, by running one command",
          "bin": "bin/createNodejsApp.js",
          "main": "src/index.js",
          "license": "MIT",
          "engines": {
            "node": ">=12.0.0"
          },
          "scripts": {
            "start": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.json --no-daemon",
            "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon src/index.js",
            "test": "jest -i --colors --verbose --detectOpenHandles",
            "test:watch": "jest -i --watchAll",
            "coverage": "jest -i --coverage",
            "coverage:coveralls": "jest -i --coverage --coverageReporters=text-lcov | coveralls",
            "lint": "eslint .",
            "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix",
            "prettier": "prettier --check **/*.js",
            "prettier:fix": "prettier --write **/*.js",
            "docker:prod": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up",
            "docker:dev": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up",
            "docker:test": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml up",
            "prepare": "husky install"
          },
          "dependencies": {
            "aws-sdk": "^2.1454.0",
            "axios": "^1.4.0",
            "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
            "compression": "^1.7.4",
            "cors": "^2.8.5",
            "cross-env": "^7.0.0",
            "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
            "express": "^4.17.1",
            "express-mongo-sanitize": "^2.0.0",
            "express-rate-limit": "^5.0.0",
            "helmet": "^4.1.0",
            "html-pdf-node": "^1.0.8",
            "http-status": "^1.4.0",
            "joi": "^17.3.0",
            "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
            "moment": "^2.24.0",
            "mongoose": "^5.7.7",
            "morgan": "^1.9.1",
            "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
            "multer-s3": "2.9.0",
            "nodemailer": "^6.3.1",
            "passport": "^0.4.0",
            "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
            "pdfkit": "^0.13.0",
            "pm2": "^5.1.0",
            "puppeteer": "^21.0.2",
            "stripe": "^12.14.0",
            "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.0.8",
            "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
            "translate": "^2.0.2",
            "validator": "^13.0.0",
            "winston": "^3.2.1",
            "xss-clean": "^0.1.1"
          },
          "devDependencies": {
            "coveralls": "^3.0.7",
            "eslint": "^7.0.0",
            "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.0.0",
            "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
            "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
            "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.0.1",
            "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
            "eslint-plugin-security": "^1.4.0",
            "faker": "^5.1.0",
            "husky": "^7.0.0",
            "jest": "^26.0.1",
            "lint-staged": "^11.0.0",
            "node-mocks-http": "^1.8.0",
            "nodemon": "^2.0.0",
            "prettier": "^2.0.5",
            "supertest": "^6.0.1"
          }
        }
```

I'm now really confused. Can anyone help me out with this, please? Is there any other way to use this translate package?

Comment: Is your start command `node main.js`?

Comment: Show your package.json file

Comment: @KaiKai no its     nodemon src/index.js

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV I have added my package.json file

Comment: Use a dynamic import or convert your entire project to ESM. You can *import a CJS module* (most of the time), but you **cannot** *require an ESM module*.

Comment: The project is a bit huge. We can't convert the entire project. Is there any other way?

Comment: @HarisGeorge yeah, use a dynamic import `const { foo } = await import('./path/to/file.js');` It's like a function that returns a Promise of the module contents and it can be used in CJS files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Keep your "type":"module" setting in package.json.

```js
// Define "require"
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Comment: Getting this error
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /src/app.js from /src/index.js not supported.